# git merge conflicts - how to resolve?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

might be best explain with an example

target branch = develop | source branch = my-branch

I ran these commands on my local before pushing my changes to bitbucket cloud

```
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
git checkout my-branch
git merge develop
git push origin my-branch
```

When I tried to create a merge request in bitbucket to merge my-branch into develop, Bitbucket is complaining there's a merge conflict.

BUT I cannot see where the conflict is (and there should be none anyway since I just merged develop into my-branch).

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? I checked develop branch for the conflicting files (there are 3) and the copies in the develop branch have my changes.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you merge two branches in Git, conflicts can arise if changes have been made to the same lines of code in both branches. In such cases, Git is unable to automatically determine which changes to keep and which to discard, and you will need to manually resolve the conflicts.If there are conflicts, Git will notify you that there are conflicts and tell you which files have conflicts. See the conflict in detail using `git status`.

Edit the file to keep the changes that you want to keep and remove the ones you want to discard. Once you have resolved all conflicts in a file, remove the conflict markers. Once you have resolved all conflicts, save the changes and add the files to the staging area using the command `git add <file>`. Then commit your changes using `git commit -m "message"`. Finally, push the changes to the remote my-branch branch using the command `git push origin my-branch`. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one working on "`my-branch`", a better practice would be to *rebase* `my-branch` on top of `origin/develop`.

Assuming you are currently working on `my-branch` (meaning `my-branch` is currently checked out)

```bash
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
git push --force
```

Then on Bitbucket side, any merge of my-branch to develop would be a trivial one.